# Importing a data frame vs creating one in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a specialized summary 'matrix' for my supervisor, and would like R to export it in a clean, readable form. As such, I am creating it from scratch basically, to tailor it to our project. My problem is I can't figure out how to get a created data frame to behave like an imported one, specifically headers.

I am most comfortable dealing with imported data frames with headers, and calling specific rows by name instead of column number:

```
iris$Sepal.Length
with(iris,Sepal.Length)
iris['Sepal.Length']
```

Now, if I want to create a data frame (or matrix, I'm not entirely sure what the difference is), I have tried the following:

```
groups<-c("Group 1", "Group 2")
factors<-c("Fac 1", "Fac 2", "Fac 3","Fac 4", "Fac 5")
x<-1:10
y<-11:20
z<-21-30

data<-cbind(groups, factors, x, y, z)
names(data) #returns NULL
data$x #clearly doesn't return the column 'x' since the matrix 'data' has no names

data<-data.frame(cbind(groups, factors, x, y, z))
names(data) #confirms that there are header names
```

So, I have created a data frame that has the columns x, y and z, but in reality I don't have a premade column to start off with. If I knew how many rows of data there would be I could simply do:

```
data<-data.frame(1:10)
data$x<-x
data$y<-y
data$z<-z
```

I tried creating an empty data frame, but it is one element big, and if I try to append a vector to it (of any length greater than 1), I get an error:

```
data<-data.frame(0)
data$x<-x #returns an error
```

My best guess at what to do is to pass through the data once to find out how long many rows of data I will have (there are several factor levels, and the summary matrix will have a row for each possible combination of factors). Then I can get the data frame started with a simple:

data<-data.frame(length(n)) #where n would be how many rows of data I would have

And follow through by creating individual vectors for each summary statistic I want and appending it to the data frame with ~$~.

Another solution I tried to play with was creating a matrix and filling in each element as I calculate it within a loop. I know the apply family is better than a loop, but to make my summary table tailored to my needs I would need to run an apply function then try to pull the individual data:

```
means<-with(iris,tapply(iris[,4],Species,mean))
means[1] #This returns the species and the mean petal width. What I need is the numeric part of this, as I will have my own headers, or possibly a separate summary table for each species.
```

I'm not sure if extracting the numerical information from the apply output is better / any easier than simply constructing my own loop to calculate the required statistics. It would be a nested loop that would first sort by group (2 runs), then an internal loop that would run by factors (5 runs) for a total of 10 runs through the data. I was thinking of creating an empty martix, and simply saving the data in the appropriate cell when it is calculated. My problem, again, is calling a specific row in a matrix. I have tried:

```
m<-matrix(0,ncol=5)
m[1,1]<-'Groups'
m[1,2]<-'Factors'
m[1,3]<-'Mean.x'
m[1,4]<-'Mean.y'
m[1,5]<-'Mean.z'

names(m) #Returns NULL
```

My desired output would look like:

```
Groups   Factors   Mean.x   Mean.y   Mean.z
Group 1   Fac 1  
Group 1   Fac 2
Group 1   Fac 3
```

Etc, for all combinations of groups and factors.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. You have two `groups`, three `factors`, and 10 x/y/z records. This causes `cbind` to throw an error. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Updated to 5 factors. Sorry!

Comment: your `means` example also doesn't work (your missing a paren). Please only post working code that has been tested instead of typing untested code into your question.

Comment: The code was missing a parenthesis at the end. Again, my bad. I didn't copy/paste far enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ddply` from plyr package for that: assume your original data frame is mydata and your new data frame where you store the result is newdata:

```
library(plyr)
newdata<-ddply(mydata,.(Groups,Factors),summarize,mean.x=mean(x),mean.y=mean(y),mean.z=mean(z))
```

Example: `mydata<-iris`

```
> newdata<-ddply(mydata,.(Species),colwise(mean))
> newdata
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Comment: Does your code work when you write `summarize` with a "z" instead of an "s"?

Comment: Yes, you can test that!

Comment: I did test it. For some reason only the "s" works in my R. Peculiar.

Comment: @BlankUsername maybe you also have `Hmisc` loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I use Rstudio so `summarize` gets called from another package as you explained on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for, but I'm a little confused by your question in general. This basically will give you a pivot table of the means in each column x,y, and z grouped by the columns 'groups' and 'factors'

```
aggregate(.~groups+factors, data=data, FUN="mean")

    groups factors  x  y z
1  Group 1   Fac 1  1  1 1
2  Group 2   Fac 1  7  6 1
3  Group 1   Fac 2  8  7 1
4  Group 2   Fac 2  3  2 1
5  Group 1   Fac 3  4  3 1
6  Group 2   Fac 3  9  8 1
7  Group 1   Fac 4 10  9 1
8  Group 2   Fac 4  5  4 1
9  Group 1   Fac 5  6  5 1
10 Group 2   Fac 5  2 10 1
```

or with the iris data grouped by Species:

```
aggregate(.~Species, data=iris, FUN="mean")

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

UPDATE: To only calculate the mean of certain columns, you can either pass only the apropriate columns of your dataset to the aggregate function (perhaps calling `subset`) or modify the formula like this:

```
aggregate(cbind(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)~Species, data=iris, FUN="mean")
```

Comment: This seems to almost be what I want. I checked out the help file for aggregate, but could you clarify some questions? I'm assuming by typing `.~` before `Species`, this is equivalent to the `by` part of the aggregate function. How would I specify if I only wanted say, Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width, instead of the mean of all of the columns in the dataset?

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to modify the `aggregate` formula

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if that's what you are looking for but there are several options to add “stuff” to data frames:

- To add a variable, just type `data$newname <- NA` (no need to know the length of the data frame or pass a vector, all rows will be filled with `NA`)
- To append data use `rbind` (the data you are adding should be another data frame with the same variables)

To fix your example, first create an empty data frame and append data as it comes:

```
data <- data.frame(x=numeric())
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(x))
```

The previous example had only one variable (x) but you can also define a data frame with several variables and no rows:

```
data <- data.frame(x=numeric(),
                   y=numeric(),
                   a=character(),
                   b=factor(levels=c("Factor 1", "Factor 2")))
```

You don't need to know how many rows you will have, but the data you are adding needs to have the same structure. If that's not the case, you need to create columns with missing values in both data frames as needed, e.g.

```
data1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1)
data2 <- data.frame(y=2, z=100:110)
rbind(data1, data2) # Error

data1$z <- NA
data2$x <- NA
rbind(data1, data2) # Now it works
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in terms of creating an empty data frame to get started!